# Mockito test iterator return always false on hasNext

Tags: java, iterator, mockito

I have this method:

```
    public void executeShadowingCF(String outputPath) throws Exception {
            try{

                Iterator<Fatt0Gdpr> notProcessedGDPRIterator = gdprDAO.getGdprRowCF(em1Fatt0);

                while(notProcessedGDPRIterator.hasNext()){
                    Fatt0Gdpr element = notProcessedGDPRIterator.next();

                    String codiceFiscale = element.getCodFiscale();

                    if(codiceFiscale != null && !codiceFiscale.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        //some operation

                    }
                    else{
                        gdprDAO.updateProcessedRow(emFatt0Update, element.getIdTecnico(), "99");
                    }

                }               

            }
            catch(Exception e ){
                log.error(e);
            }
            finally{
                emFatt0.close();
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to test it with mockito, but when I execute the test the `notProcessedGDPRIterator.hasNext()` return always false so I can't go inside the while loop.
This is my test method:

```
       @Test
        public void testExecuteShadowingCF() {    
            try {
                EntityManager em1Fatt0 = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
                EntityManager emFatt0 = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
                Fatt0GdprService service = new Fatt0GdprService();          
                Fatt0GdprDAO fatt0GdprDAO = new Fatt0GdprDAO(); 
                Query queryFind = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
                Iterator<Fatt0Gdpr> mockIterator = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
                Mockito.when(
                        emFatt0.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString(),
                                eq(Fatt0Gdpr.class))).thenReturn(queryFind);    
                Mockito.when(fatt0GdprDAO.getGdprRowNDG(emFatt0)).thenReturn(mockIterator); 

                Mockito.when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
                Mockito.when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(new Fatt0Gdpr());

                service.setEmFatt0Updater(emFatt0);
                EntityTransaction trxMock = Mockito.mock(EntityTransaction.class);
                Mockito.when(service.getEmFatt0Updater().getTransaction())
                        .thenReturn(trxMock);

                String outputPath = "U:/RTC_U0E7069/fatt0_SRC/SRC/fatt0-gdpr-batch/target/diraliases/BATCHROOT/ITT/out";

                service.executeShadowingCF(outputPath);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Someone can help me to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: what is the class of `gdprDAO` and argument parameter for `getGdprRowCF()`?

Comment: public Iterator<Fatt0Gdpr> getGdprRowCF(EntityManager emFatt0){
  StringBuilder nativeQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  String nativeQuery = nativeQueryBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM TABLE_GDPR WHERE FLG_ELABORATO = 'N' AND COD_FISCALE IS NOT NULL ").toString();
  Query queryFind = emFatt0.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery,Fatt0Gdpr.class);  
  return queryFind.getResultStream().iterator();
 }

Comment: But the method called `getGdprRowCF()` not `getGdprRowNDG()` in test target class?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that mocking iterators is insane: your method is called with `em1Fatt0`, but your mock is set up with `emFatt0`. Are you sure you are stubbing the correct calls?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should mock `gdprDAO` and define the behavior of `getGdprRowCF` and return `mockIterator`

```
Mockito.when(gdprDAO.getGdprRowCF(em1Fatt0)).thenReturn(mockIterator);
```

---

Best practice to define `List` and send it as an iterator rather than `mockIterator`

```
List<Fatt0Gdpr> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Fatt0Gdpr());
Mockito.when(gdprDAO.getGdprRowCF(em1Fatt0)).thenReturn(list.iterator());
```

Comment: with your suggest now i have this error:org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Itr cannot be returned by getResultStream()
getResultStream() should return Stream

Comment: Check the method name and this is the idea how to do this task

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock iterators.

You should only use a mock when behavior is too difficult to create otherwise. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object#Motivation):

> If an object has any of the following characteristics, it may be useful to use a mock object in its place:
>
> - the object supplies non-deterministic results (e.g. the current time or the current temperature);
> - it has states that are difficult to create or reproduce (e.g. a network error);
> - it is slow (e.g. a complete database, which would have to be initialized before the test);
> - it does not yet exist or may change behavior;
> - it would have to include information and methods exclusively for testing purposes (and not for its actual task).

Iterators don't have any of these properties (necessarily): just make the iterator-returning method use `Arrays.asList().iterator()`, or similar.

```
List<Fatt0Gdpr> fakeData = Arrays.asList(new Fatt0Gdpr());
Mockito.when(fatt0GdprDAO.getGdprRowNDG(emFatt0)).thenReturn(fakeData.iterator());
```

Comment: You're mocking `when(fatt0GdprDAO.getGdprRowNDG(emFatt0))`, but your method calls `getGdprRowCF`. Is that significant?

Comment: sorry the  correct method is getGdprRowCF but i have always the same error...

Comment: OK, but the code you're showing sets the output for `getGdprRowNDG`. Did you copy+paste your test method (in which case you're mocking the wrong method and need to fix the code to call the right one), or did you type it out here (in which case you've made a transcription error)?

Comment: in my code i have the correct method name...it isn't the problem..